# Executing pydocstyle also on filenames starting with 'test_'

Tags: python

I've been working on a test framework, and use the *pydocstyle* tool (formerly known as *pep257*) on my source files. By default it ignores source files whose names start with `test_`, which is unfortunate in my case.

How can I run the tool also on these files?

I've tried running `pydocstyle --match='test_'` but it didn't work.

The documentation is provided here: http://pep257.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--match='test_'` would run the tool on files that are literally named `test_`.

Try `--match='.*\.py'` to match all filenames ending on `.py`.